# jquery correct syncronous ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, .when

i need to call a jquery ajax funtion inside a function and check response data

```
function checkInput(){
    var success;
    $.ajax({...}).then(function (data) {
        success = data.response
        console.log(success); // true/false correct!
        if (success)
            call_other_func(); // works
    });
    console.log(success); // undefined;

    return success; // i need to return success variable        
}
```

Other function call checkInput

```
if (checkInput()){
        console.log('correct input value'); 
    }
else{
     call_error_validation_func();
}
```

With async:false works but it's not correct way.

how can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'r problem is understanding Asynchronous calls in javascript.
What you should probably do is return a delegate and then take the returned value when the ajax call is done.

Here's an example :

```
function checkInput(){
    var success;
    var delegate = $.ajax({...});   

    return delegate;
}

var delegate = checkInput();

delegate.done(function(data){
    console.log(data); //will show you'r results

    // Do whatever you need here
});
```